# Order of JOIN results

Tags: postgresql, join

I have this query

```
SELECT orden.id,
array_to_string(array_agg(observaciones.fecha_hora),'<br>') as observaciones
FROM orden
LEFT JOIN observacion observaciones ON observaciones.orden_id = orden.id
GROUP BY orden.id
```

and it's returning this:

```
orden.id = 5878  
observaciones
2012-03-15 01:39:11
2012-03-15 01:40:28
2012-03-15 01:40:42
2012-03-15 09:09:08
2012-03-15 09:11:10
2012-03-15 01:18:34
2012-03-15 01:19:27
2012-03-15 09:17:01
2012-03-15 09:17:36
2012-03-15 03:16:58
2012-03-15 01:21:01
2012-03-15 03:17:06
2012-03-15 03:17:26
2012-03-15 01:27:33
2012-03-15 03:18:05
2012-03-15 03:24:56
2012-03-15 03:49:24
2012-03-15 01:27:43
2012-03-15 01:38:30
2012-03-15 06:30:13
```

and the question is, how can I obtain those date time in order DESC
I can't do a subquery because I'm optimizing a old query, I really need a JOIN.
I'm using postgresql.

Comment: `ORDER BY date_column` at the end of your query

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally i did it this way...

```
    SELECT 
    orden.id,
    array_to_string(array_agg(observaciones.fecha_hora),'<br>') as observaciones
    FROM orden
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT orden_id, fecha_hora FROM observacion ORDER BY fecha_hora DESC
    ) as observaciones ON observaciones.orden_id = orden.id
    GROUP BY orden.id
```

Thanks to all..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about PostgreSQL, but in SQL you could just throw it into a temp table, then order the temp table.

```
SELECT  orden.id
,       array_to_string(array_agg(observaciones.fecha_hora),'<br>') as observaciones
INTO #orden
FROM orden
LEFT JOIN observacion observaciones 
    ON observaciones.orden_id = orden.id
GROUP BY orden.id

SELECT id
,       observaciones
FROM #orden
ORDER BY observaciones

DROP TABLE #orden
```

Comment: I can't use it, because table "observation" has 2.500.000 rows... and I need to reduce time from 40 minutes to less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want order the result rows by date desc, just add ORDER BY "field" DESC:

```
SELECT orden.id,
array_to_string(array_agg(observaciones.fecha_hora),'<br>') as observaciones
FROM orden
LEFT JOIN observacion observaciones ON observaciones.orden_id = orden.id
GROUP BY orden.id
ORDER BY observaciones.fecha_hora DESC
```

Comment: Maybe i don't explained it well... i need to order just the JOIN results.